# How to get Image tags from html using JavaScript having alt=checked?

Tags: javascript

There is an image tag in my website as shown below. There are multiple image tags and some have `alt="checked"` and some have `alt="unchecked"`. All image tags are followed by `<input type="hidden">` as shown

```html
<img src="./images/checked.gif"  alt="checked"  onClick="javascript:methodname('param1','param2','1234')" />
<input type="hidden" id="1234" name="1234" value="check" displayname="displyname" pcID="4704.51127.28929.4371"  />
```

I need to get all the values (either from name or id or parameter of the JavaScript, anything would be fine) for those images which have `alt="checked"`.

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into with a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 1):

You can get all the image elements with alt=“checked” with `var images = document.querySelectorAll('img[alt="checked"]');`. Then, you can get the ids and whatever other attributes you want using

```
for (let image of images) {
    let id = image.getAttribute('id');
    // Do stuff
}
```